# Sending MMS into different Android devices

Tags: android, messaging, mms

I need to send MMS. Into my hero this code looks ugly but works:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.SEND_MSG"); 
   sendIntent.putExtra("address", toText); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");

sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", textMessage); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg"); 
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

But it seems to me that on the other devices it doesn't work at all. 
I want to send directly to main messaging app without any choices(the better solution of course - direct from my app). Because not sure that all of them would handle it properly.
If anybody could recommend any third-party library I'll be appretiate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this (change to your need and add images etc...):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mmsto:<number>");
intent.putExtra("address", <number>);
intent.putExtra("subject", <subject>);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above is the best I could come up with which works on HTC/Nexus/SE from 1.6 to 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

send from your app ?

before startActivity, you can

intent.setClassName("your package name", "your class name");

startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.Which will launches all the apps which can handle the intent.

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
//In case of multiple file
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, <List of uris>);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, <singleUri>);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(intent);
```