# Sending MMS programmatically on Android

Tags: android, mms

I am having an issue with a task I'm supposed to do,
I'm supposed to send MMS using our own interface on android 2.1
so as you can guess calling the default Activity is out of the question.
So my question, is there a way to programatically send MMS using the android SDK
without calling their intent, 
I tried importing the MMS app in eclipse but most of the classes are com.google.android
which means they are not open sourced, so I have no idea how to get them if possible,
or, how to mimic them. I was even thinking of using reflection to load them from Dalvik, but I think that this is a final effort and may not bring results.

any ideas?

btw, I found

[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android)

[Sending MMS into different Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165516/sending-mms-into-different-android-devices)

but they do not work.. (with out the proprietary classes)

Comment: When you say "Default Activity" what do you mean? Do you mean calling the mms application directly?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this question was left unanswered for a while, I kinda found a way back then, just forgot to post. 
however I got the original MMS app and crippled the binary classes and added corresponding requirements to finish since most of them were private to the build system. 
The ONLY way do make an mms sender in android (that I know of) is to build the app with the source tree. In that manner you will have access to the restricted MMS functions and it is generally very easy since there is a MMSManager in the source it's self, although this is not public in the sdk. 
I know my answer is a bit vague, but for those of you going down this path.. prepare for some bumps on the road.. :)

Comment: Dude... this is a really old thread :) like.. anchient..
In anycase.. I did some really *strange* things back then.
What I would suggest, download the source and build your app from IN the applications folder so that it has all the MMS libs it needs. and you can copy the code from the MMS app in terms of what it does when it sends an MMS.
Post a new question and give me the link.. and I will help if I can

Comment: were you able to send MMS images with Samsung phones?

Comment: Yes, I was, it was OS specific not device specific. But if you build you'r app within the source you won't have to do all the "dirty hacking" I did. you will be able just to call whatever they call upon send and it will be working like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Tancho. At the moment I am able to send an mms and receive one... The problem That I'm facing now is saving the message into my outbox... I'm following: http://maximbogatov.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/mms-in-android-part-2-working-with-mms-storage/ which isn't too helpful. any advice?

Comment: WelL i haven't had the need to work with it in a while, what I would suggest is getting the db from the emulator, inspecting and inputing data directly in the database. I believe SMS/MMS use the same content provider and you're allowed to read/write it.

Comment: Any chance you can overlook my insertion code... see what's wrong?

Comment: No prob.. but.. I think you should get out of the comments section with that one.. maybe even post a new question and give me the url to the question :)

Comment: Do you have any example of how to build the app with the source tree?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble with sending MMS. I would really appreciate it if you could help me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448316/cannot-send-mms

Answer (score 0):

Like SmsManager there is something like MmsManager api which is not being exposed by android framework.

So to send MMS first you have to acquire MMS netwotk and then make http calls.

```
/**
 * Synchronously acquire MMS network connectivity
 *
 * @throws MmsNetworkException If failed permanently or timed out
 */

void acquireNetwork() throws MmsNetworkException {
    Log.i(MmsService.TAG, "Acquire MMS network");
    synchronized (this) {
        try {
            mUseCount++;
            mWaitCount++;
            if (mWaitCount == 1) {
                // Register the receiver for the first waiting request
                registerConnectivityChangeReceiverLocked();
            }
            long waitMs = sNetworkAcquireTimeoutMs;
            final long beginMs = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            do {
                if (!isMobileDataEnabled()) {
                    // Fast fail if mobile data is not enabled
                    throw new MmsNetworkException("Mobile data is disabled");
                }
                // Always try to extend and check the MMS network connectivity
                // before we start waiting to make sure we don't miss the change
                // of MMS connectivity. As one example, some devices fail to send
                // connectivity change intent. So this would make sure we catch
                // the state change.
                if (extendMmsConnectivityLocked()) {
                    // Connected
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    wait(Math.min(waitMs, NETWORK_ACQUIRE_WAIT_INTERVAL_MS));
                } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.w(MmsService.TAG, "Unexpected exception", e);
                }
                // Calculate the remaining time to wait
                waitMs = sNetworkAcquireTimeoutMs - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - beginMs);
            } while (waitMs > 0);
            // Last check
            if (extendMmsConnectivityLocked()) {
                return;
            } else {
                // Reaching here means timed out.
                throw new MmsNetworkException("Acquiring MMS network timed out");
            }
        } finally {
            mWaitCount--;
            if (mWaitCount == 0) {
                // Receiver is used to listen to connectivity change and unblock
                // the waiting requests. If nobody's waiting on change, there is
                // no need for the receiver. The auto extension timer will try
                // to maintain the connectivity periodically.
                unregisterConnectivityChangeReceiverLocked();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the piece of code which I got from android native source code.

```
/**
 * Run the MMS request.
 *
 * @param context the context to use
 * @param networkManager the MmsNetworkManager to use to setup MMS network
 * @param apnSettingsLoader the APN loader
 * @param carrierConfigValuesLoader the carrier config loader
 * @param userAgentInfoLoader the user agent info loader
 */



public void sendMms(final Context context, final MmsNetworkManager networkManager,
        final ApnSettingsLoader apnSettingsLoader,
        final CarrierConfigValuesLoader carrierConfigValuesLoader,
        final UserAgentInfoLoader userAgentInfoLoader) {
    Log.i(MmsService.TAG, "Execute " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    int result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    int httpStatusCode = 0;
    byte[] response = null;
    final Bundle mmsConfig = carrierConfigValuesLoader.get(MmsManager.DEFAULT_SUB_ID);
    if (mmsConfig == null) {
        Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "Failed to load carrier configuration values");
        result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_CONFIGURATION_ERROR;
    } else if (!loadRequest(context, mmsConfig)) {
        Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "Failed to load PDU");
        result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_IO_ERROR;
    } else {
        // Everything's OK. Now execute the request.
        try {
            // Acquire the MMS network
            networkManager.acquireNetwork();
            // Load the potential APNs. In most cases there should be only one APN available.
            // On some devices on which we can't obtain APN from system, we look up our own
            // APN list. Since we don't have exact information, we may get a list of potential
            // APNs to try. Whenever we found a successful APN, we signal it and return.
            final String apnName = networkManager.getApnName();
            final List<ApnSettingsLoader.Apn> apns = apnSettingsLoader.get(apnName);
            if (apns.size() < 1) {
                throw new ApnException("No valid APN");
            } else {
                Log.d(MmsService.TAG, "Trying " + apns.size() + " APNs");
            }
            final String userAgent = userAgentInfoLoader.getUserAgent();
            final String uaProfUrl = userAgentInfoLoader.getUAProfUrl();
            MmsHttpException lastException = null;
            for (ApnSettingsLoader.Apn apn : apns) {
                Log.i(MmsService.TAG, "Using APN ["
                        + "MMSC=" + apn.getMmsc() + ", "
                        + "PROXY=" + apn.getMmsProxy() + ", "
                        + "PORT=" + apn.getMmsProxyPort() + "]");
                try {
                    final String url = getHttpRequestUrl(apn);
                    // Request a global route for the host to connect
                    requestRoute(networkManager.getConnectivityManager(), apn, url);
                    // Perform the HTTP request
                    response = doHttp(
                            context, networkManager, apn, mmsConfig, userAgent, uaProfUrl);
                    // Additional check of whether this is a success
                    if (isWrongApnResponse(response, mmsConfig)) {
                        throw new MmsHttpException(0/*statusCode*/, "Invalid sending address");
                    }
                    // Notify APN loader this is a valid APN
                    apn.setSuccess();
                    result = Activity.RESULT_OK;
                    break;
                } catch (MmsHttpException e) {
                    Log.w(MmsService.TAG, "HTTP or network failure", e);
                    lastException = e;
                }
            }
            if (lastException != null) {
                throw lastException;
            }
        } catch (ApnException e) {
            Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "MmsRequest: APN failure", e);
            result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_INVALID_APN;
        } catch (MmsNetworkException e) {
            Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "MmsRequest: MMS network acquiring failure", e);
            result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_UNABLE_CONNECT_MMS;
        } catch (MmsHttpException e) {
            Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "MmsRequest: HTTP or network I/O failure", e);
            result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_HTTP_FAILURE;
            httpStatusCode = e.getStatusCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(MmsService.TAG, "MmsRequest: unexpected failure", e);
            result = SmsManager.MMS_ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
        } finally {
            // Release MMS network
            networkManager.releaseNetwork();
        }
    }
    // Process result and send back via PendingIntent
    returnResult(context, result, response, httpStatusCode);
}




/**
 * Request the route to the APN (either proxy host or the MMSC host)
 *
 * @param connectivityManager the ConnectivityManager to use
 * @param apn the current APN
 * @param url the URL to connect to
 * @throws MmsHttpException for unknown host or route failure
 */
private static void requestRoute(final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager,
        final ApnSettingsLoader.Apn apn, final String url) throws MmsHttpException {
    String host = apn.getMmsProxy();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(host)) {
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        host = uri.getHost();
    }
    boolean success = false;
    // Request route to all resolved host addresses
    try {
        for (final InetAddress addr : InetAddress.getAllByName(host)) {
            final boolean requested = requestRouteToHostAddress(connectivityManager, addr);
            if (requested) {
                success = true;
                Log.i(MmsService.TAG, "Requested route to " + addr);
            } else {
                Log.i(MmsService.TAG, "Could not requested route to " + addr);
            }
        }
        if (!success) {
            throw new MmsHttpException(0/*statusCode*/, "No route requested");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.w(MmsService.TAG, "Unknown host " + host);
        throw new MmsHttpException(0/*statusCode*/, "Unknown host");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -10):

```
 private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {        
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, SMS.class), 0);                
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);        
    }    
}
```

try this

Comment: i think he is talking about MMS, not SMS.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's always better to provide a short description for a sample code to improve the post accuracy :)