# Sending MMS from android app prepared but not sent

Tags: java, android, mms

I'm facing a problem on my android app, I have a function to send MMS to a phone number but my application only prepare the mms and don't send it.

as you can see here:
[image]

I can send SMS without any troubles but not MMS

My permissions in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Here is my fonction

```
    public void sendMMS(String sendTO, String msg) {
        //File ImageFolderDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MesApplis" + File.separator + "Internet");
        //String myFileImage = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/M1F1-Alaw-AFsp.wav";
        String myFileImage = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/alphatest.png";
        Uri attachedFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(myFileImage));
        Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND,attachedFileUri);
        //mmsIntent.setType("audio/wav");
        mmsIntent.setType("image/png");
        mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,attachedFileUri);
        mmsIntent.putExtra("address",sendTO);
        mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",msg);
        startActivity(mmsIntent);
}
```

Comment: does the device you're working with support MMS?
When i bought my phone, i had to put some extra settings for it to be able to send mms

Comment: @LenaBru i think so I'm using samsung s8 to test my app

Comment: are you able to send MMS manually from the SMS app ?

Comment: @LenaBru Yes sure

Comment: which permissions did you specify in the android manifest?

Comment: @LenaBru I updated the post with the permissions

Comment: please try adding this permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
`

Comment: @LenaBru Same issue :/

Comment: @LenaBru Can you please confirm me that it is possible to send a MMS with an MP3 or PNG from an android app to an anthor number ?

Comment: with recent changes to the android system, i'm not sure, but if the sms app is able to do it, your app - declared as an sms app, should be able to do it

Comment: please check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475292/2136812
apparently in order to be able to send mms, you need to force it to be on the mobile network

Comment: @LenaBru Thank's i'm loogking at it but can't understand how to integrate it in my project