# MMS between 2 Android devices in emulators

Tags: android, mms

Can I test the MMS code with two emulators? Is any service providers needed for enabling MMS?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("address", 5556);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Hi");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/img.png"));
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send Image To:"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Android SDK Release Notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html):

> It is not possible to send MMS messages between emulator instances.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ACTION_SENDTO` or check this: [Sending MMS into different Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165516/sending-mms-into-different-android-devices).